# SharePoint 2010 Email Outlook File to Library with attachments embedded

Tags: sharepoint-2010

The only way I have found to retain attachments with an email from Outlook to SharePoint is to do a save as .msg and drag and drop into the SharePoint library.

I would like to set the library to receive email and retain the attachment as part of the email.  I don't want the attachments to separate from the email when they arrive in the library.

Is there an add-in to Outlook or a fix in SharePoint 2010??????

Comment: Here's 5 out of the box ways to get email from Outlook and into SharePoint and the pro's and con's of each. Hopefully you will find what you are looking for. [Blog: Five Out of the box ways to get email into SharePoint](http://camerondwyer.wordpress.com/2012/01/04/five-out-of-the-box-ways-to-get-email-into-sharepoint)

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:
1. Stick with the SharePoint options like adding attachments to the library or to a sub folder of the library based on subject or sender.
2. Write a custom email event handler. Here is an example for 2007, but it should work in 2010 as well: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/malag/archive/2009/05/13/attachments-disappear-with-custom-email-event-handler.aspx

marco

Answer (score 0):

Marco, when I created the EventHandler to try and retain the message and attachment when activated it still came through as it was before by separating the message and attachment in two different files

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are add-ins. I have used some 3rd Party tools for Outlook and SharePoint:

- Scinaptic's OnePlaceMail
- Colligo
- Macroview

They are all good.